# Why are my sidekiq scheduled cron jobs not running on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cron, backgroundworker, sidekiq

I wrote several scheduled jobs for an app I am coding in Rails. These jobs go scrapp data for tennis games and results. They run perfectly when scheduled on my computer. They also run on heroku when I am setting a cron expression every minute '* * * * *'.

But when I try to set an expression for every four hours, it stops running but the heroku worker is up and does not crash so I really does not understand what is happening.
I tried several ways to write my cron expressions.

Here is the last I tried in sidekiq.yml:

```
:schedule:
  set_scrapp_state_job:
    cron: '1 1,13 * * *'
    class: SetScrappStateJob
  set_scrapp_drawed_job:
    cron: '1 2,14 * * *'
    class: SetScrappDrawedJob
  fill_participants_and_create_first_round_games_job:
    cron: '1 3,15 * * *'
    class: FillParticipantsAndCreateFirstRoundGamesJob
  reset_participants_while_qualified_and_luckyloser_in_draw_job:
    cron: '1 4,16 * * *'
    class: ResetParticipantsWhileQualifiedAndLuckyloserInDrawJob
  fill_wins_with_bye_job:
    cron: '1 5,17 * * *'
    class: FillWinsWithByeJob
  fill_games_results_for_current_tournaments_job:
    cron: '1 0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22 * * *'
    class: FillGamesResultsForCurrentTournamentsJob
```

Answer (score 1):

It was in fact a problem with the plan I was using on Heroku. The free plan makes the dinos sleep after 30 minutes, even if they have background jobs to do, I thought it was only the case for web dynos. So I changed for the cheapest plan and now it works because the dynos aren't idle anymore :)